# Find $\overline{\lim}\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{2}{n}+\frac{3}{n}-...+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{n}{n}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Find $\overline{\lim}\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{2}{n}+\frac{3}{n}-...+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{n}{n}\right)$

$\frac{1}{n}-\frac{2}{n}+\frac{3}{n}-...+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{n}{n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k-1}k$

How to evaluate sum $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k-1}k$?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the over-bar on the lim?

Comment: Suppose for the moment that $n$ is even; then $\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1} k = \sum_{k=1}^n k - 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n/2} 2k = \sum_{k=1}^n k - 4 \sum_{k=1}^{n/2} k$. Do you know the formula for the sum of the first $n$ integers? Then you can simplify this. Something very similar will work when $n$ is odd.

Comment: @Patrick Stevens Limit superior of a sequence.

Comment: The sum seems to be positive for odd $n$ and negative for even $n$

Comment: The absolute value of the partial sum of the series is bounded be $1/n$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The first few values of your sum are $1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4, \ldots$. Try to derive a general formula for the sum depending on whether $n$ is even or odd. Then prove this formula via induction.

Comment: Are the first four values not $1, -3/2,2/3,-1/2$ ?

Comment: @CalvinKhor The question was how to evalate the sum $\sum(-1)^{k-1}k$

Comment: whoops. Thanks for clearing that up :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the sum:

$$
S=\sum_{k=1}^{n} x^k=x\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}
$$

Take its derivative with respect to $x$:

$$
S'=\sum_{k=1}^{n}kx^{k-1}=\frac{nx^{n+1}-(n+1)x^n+1}{{(1-x)}^2}
$$

So for $x=-1$ you would get:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}k{(-1)}^{k-1}=\frac{n{(-1)}^{n+1}-(n+1){(-1)}^{n}+1}{4}
$$

Now the limit would be:

$$
{lim}_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{S'}{n}={lim}_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n{(-1)}^{n+1}-(n+1){(-1)}^n+1}{4n}\\
={lim}_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{{(-1)}^{n+1}(2n+1)+1}{4n}\\
={lim}_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{{(-1)}^{n+1}(2+\frac{1}{n})+\frac{1}{n}}{4}
$$

From the above we see that the limit doesnt exist as it would be either $\frac{1}{2}$ or $-\frac{1}{2}$ depending on wether $n$ is even or odd.  But as Michael pointed out, I was supposed to find the limit superior in which case the answer would be $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: The lim-sup, which as display-error says in the comments above, is the limit with an overline, would take the odd terms, with a lim-sup of $1/2$.

Comment: @Michael So it means the lim sup would be $1/2$?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: Okay now I see. I'm new to the concepts of sup and inf of a limit.Thanks @Michael